# returning select items in Elasticsearch array

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm in the process of refining an Elasticsearch search and came across an issue. For reference, I have a collection of documents that each have the following field:

"ingredients" : [ingredient 1, ingredient 2, ingredient 3]

an example of what I'd like to do:

search my documents for all documents with 'sugar' listed in the ingredients; then, return all ingredients that contain the word 'milk.'

through aggregation (code below), I'm able to get all distinct ingredients returned from all documents where the field "ingredients" contains 'sugar.' however, I'm at a loss as to how to further filter these results -- I've tried using a post-filter and a filter within the aggregation to no avail.

if anyone could help me with this, it'd be greatly appreciated!

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "ingredients": {
          "value": "Sugar"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [ 
    "ingredients"
  ],
  "size" : 0, 
  "aggs": {
        "Ingreds": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ingredients",
            "size": 50,
          }
        }
  }
}
```

And, here's the mapping:

```
{
  "recipe_cookbook": {
    "mappings": {
      "searchable-recipes": {
        "properties": {
          "recipe": {
            "properties": {
              "ingredients": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "doc_values": false
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your mapping?

Comment: added mapping to original question!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this?

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "term": {
                      "ingredients": "Sugar"
                   }
               },
               {
                   "term": {
                      "ingredients": "milk"
                   }
               }
            ]
          }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": [ 
    "ingredients"
  ],
  "size" : 0, 
  "aggs": {
        "Ingreds": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ingredients",
            "size": 50
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Prateek: 

Thanks for your comment!

I've tried similar queries, but ultimately what such a query would return is the entire field (i.e. the entire array) for any document whose 'ingredients' field contains an item that matches 'milk' and an item that matches 'Sugar'; e.g., if the field in question was: 

'ingredients' : ['milk', 'Sugar', 'pancakes'] 

the query would return the entire field (whereas I'd only be looking for it to return the 'milk' item). does that make sense?

Comment: It always returns the field value. To get only item, you are looking for in array, you should use script field and return only the matching values.